# Vertically align multiple lines with parent div

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

How can I align the middle div so both lines are vertically centered?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.second {
  text-align: left;
  flex-grow: 2;
}
img {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x75">
  </div>
  <div class="second">
   <h2>Please vertically center both</h2>
   <p>of us!</p>
  </div>
  <div>
   Right
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Middle `Div` is already vertically center. you can see that spacing because of default margin heading and paragraph element takes when rendering in browser

Comment: Add this to your code: `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` https://jsfiddle.net/27fdcaso/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  `h2,p{margin:0}`  to remove the default margin given to `h2` and `p` tag

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.second {
  text-align: left;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

img {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
h2,p{margin:0}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x75">
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <h2>Please vertically center both</h2>
    <p>of us!</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    Right
  </div>
</div>
```